# Preserve volatile in nested types

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T>
struct S {
    using type = T;
};

volatile S<int> s;

template<typename T>
void f(T& v) {
    using n = typename T::type;

    S<n>::_; // to show

}

int main() {
     f(s);
}
```

In `f`  the `T`  is deduced to `volatile S<int>`, but `n` is
only `int`. What do I have to do to preserve the `volatile`, that is, 
to have `n` be `volatile int`?

Comment: how do you know it isnt?

Comment: The `volatile` qualifier is only for `s`, not for `S<int>::type`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude isnt `T` deduced to be `volatile S<int>` ? if not the code has UB as far as I understood

Comment: Just added a debug statement

Comment: @user463035818 Yes `T` for the `f` function is `volatile S<int>`. But `T` in `S` is `int`.

Comment: My simple solution would be to use std::conditional together with std::is_volatile<>

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ah right, I was a bit confused, `type` is not a member variable but just a typedef

Comment: `volatile S<int> s;` makes little sense (`S<T>` is a traits). Moreover, `volatile` is very rarely what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using n = typename std::conditional< std::is_volatile<T>::value, 
            volatile typename T::type,
            typename T::type >::type;
```

Adds `volatile` to `n` if `T` is `volatile`.

Answer (score 3):

For funsies. If you need to do this sort of thing often, it's possible to encapsulate it in a meta-function. Here's a possible implementation in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class Trait, typename=void>
struct propogate_cv_to_type{};

template<class Trait>
struct propogate_cv_to_type<Trait, std::void_t<typename Trait::type>>
{ using type = typename Trait::type; }; 

template<class Trait>
struct propogate_cv_to_type<Trait const, std::void_t<typename Trait::type>>
{ using type = typename Trait::type const; }; 

template<class Trait>
struct propogate_cv_to_type<Trait volatile, std::void_t<typename Trait::type>>
{ using type = typename Trait::type volatile; }; 

template<class Trait>
struct propogate_cv_to_type<Trait const volatile, std::void_t<typename Trait::type>>
{ using type = typename Trait::type const volatile; };
```

It's SFINAE friendly, so if the type being passed doesn't have a `::type` member, it will not either. Otherwise, it exposes the same type by forwarding qualifiers onto it.

[Here it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/441523ac5a606f21) is when applied to your example.